# conversion from float to integer

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

i have following simpled  algorithm for calculation roots of  quadratic equation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float x,x1;
    x=0;x1=0;
    int a=1;
    int b;
    int c;
    cout<<"enter the second term:"<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"enter the third term:";
    cin>>c;
    float d=b^2-4*a*c;
      if (d<0){

          cout<<"the equation  has not real solution :"<<endl;
              }


      else   if (d==0) {  x=(-b/2); x1=x;}
      else
      {
          x=(-b+sqrt(d))/2;x1=(-b-sqrt(d))/2;


      }
      cout<<"roots are :"<<x<< " "<<x1<< "  "<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me warning

```
arning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
```

and when i enter -6 and 9 it gives  that roots are 6 and zero which of course is not true please help me

Comment: Work on your variable names! What’s x? x1? a? b? c? d? Oh. My. God. Also, correct indentation. And what are these empty lines doing there?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I'd say in this case it's okay since it's obviously the quadratic formula which by convention uses those letters

Comment: @Konrad They're the variables in the quadratic equation.

Comment: And for that matter, *use proper indentation*. Appearance matters.

Comment: @isbadawi, Dan: They are certainly not the names *we* used in quadratic equations (neither in Germany, nor in France). Don’t assume everybody is using the same conventions.

Comment: I feel I should point out even with all the answers below, the quadradic equation he shows is incorrect.  The denominator should not be `2`, but should be `(2*a)`

Comment: @Mooing Duck He is solving the normalised equation (`a = 1` in the whole program). Still, it is weird :)

Comment: @Nicolas Grebille: Good call, I missed that a=1 in the whole program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is the bitwise xor operator, not the power, as you probably think. To raise a number to an arbitrary power, use `std::pow` (from the standard header `cmath`). For powers of two, you can just use `x * x`.

Answer (score 3):

b^2 means to use the XOR operator, which I don't think is what you meant to use.  Try using b*b.  Also it might be helpful to declare a, b, and c as floats and not ints.

Answer (score 2):

besides the correct remarks on the xor operation

you cannot do all the calculations on int and then cast it to float. this way the div result is rounded. try to cast b in the middle of the calculation like (float)b. or define all a,b,c and d as floats

Comment: That won't help in the way that you think it will. Extremely large integers cannot be accurately represented by float (32 bit integer -> 23 bit fraction means loss of accuracy). Best to just use double.

Answer (score 1):

^ is a bitwise xor operator i.e why the compiler is giving warning.Try using pow function declared in math.h header file.